# Magento crob job 404 not found page when executing from browser

Tags: magento, cron

I have two Magento installations, one is my primary store and other for testing, I have an installation on a subdomain: mystore.mydomain.com this is for testing, when I go to the browser to: mystore.mydomain.com/cron.php it returns a 404 error, in my primary installation mydomain.com/cron.php returns a blank page and queue newsletters start sending, cron.php is indeed located at the root of mystore.mydomain.com, I also did mystore.mydomain.com/magento-cleanup.php and the path works, so the problem is not the path. What is the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below two things. 
1. cron.php file is exists in the root of magento.
2. Its not disable by htaccess. We can disable cron.php by htaccess.